# Inserting value in List of values of a Key in Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a `rowsDictionary` that its keys point to a list of `EmployeeSummary` classes.
In those `EmployeeSummary` classes we also have a string property of `Delivery_System`

I am looping through this in this way but now stuck in the part that I want to have a `deliverySystemFinder dictioanry` that its keys are `combinedKey` as below and the value for each key is a list of distinct `delivery_system` values

```
//rowsDictionary is a Dictionary<string, List<EmployeeSummary>>

Dictionary<string, List<string>> deliverySystemFinder = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach (string key in rowsDictionary.Keys)
{
    List<EmployeeSummary> empList = rowsDictionary[key];
    foreach (EmployeeSummary emp in empList)
    {
        string combinedKey = emp.LastName.Trim().ToUpper() + emp.FirstName.Trim().ToUpper();
        string delivery_system = emp.Delivery_System;
        // so now I should go and 
        //A) does deliverySystemFinder have this combinedKey? if not add it. 
        //B) Does combinedKey in the list of its values already have the value for delivery_system? if it does not then add it 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work, for start:

```
foreach (string key in rowsDictionary.Keys)
{
    List<EmployeeSummary> empList = rowsDictionary[key];
    foreach (EmployeeSummary emp in empList)
    {
        string combinedKey = emp.LastName.Trim().ToUpper() +
            emp.FirstName.Trim().ToUpper();

        string delivery_system = emp.Delivery_System;

        List<string> systems = null;

        // check if the dictionary contains the list
        if (!deliverySystemFinder.TryGetValue(combinedKey, out systems))
        {
            // if not, create it and add it 
            systems = new List<string>();
            deliverySystemFinder[combinedKey] = systems;
        }

        // check if the list contains the value and add it
        if (!systems.Contains(delivery_system))
            systems.Add(delivery_system);
    }
}
```

Now, a couple of remarks:

1. It doesn't make sense to iterate through `Keys`, and then do a lookup in each iteration. You can directly iterate `KeyValuePair`s using a `foreach` loop.
2. Using concatenated strings as unique keys often fails. In this case, what happens if you have users `{ LastName="Some", FirstName="Body" }` and `{ LastName="So", FirstName="Mebody" }` in your list?
3. Checking if a `List` contains a value is a `O(n)` operation. You would greatly improve performance if you used a `HashSet<string>` instead.

Finally, the simplest way to achieve what you're trying to do is to ditch those loops and simply use:

```
// returns a Dictionary<EmployeeSummary, List<string>>
// which maps each distinct EmployeeSummary into a list of
// distinct delivery systems
var groupByEmployee = rowsDictionary
    .SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value)
    .GroupBy(s => s, new EmployeeSummaryEqualityComparer())
    .ToDictionary(
         s => s.Key, 
         s => s.Select(x => x.Delivery_System).Distinct().ToList());
```

With `EmployeeSummaryEqualityComparer` defined something like:

```
class EmployeeSummaryEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<EmployeeSummary>
{
    public bool Equals(EmployeeSummary x, EmployeeSummary y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, null))
            return object.ReferenceEquals(y, null);

        return 
            x.FirstName == y.FirstName &&
            x.LastName == y.LastName &&
            ... (depending on what constitutes 'equal' for you)
    }

    public int GetHashCode(EmployeeSummary x)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var h = 31;   // null checks might not be necessary?
            h = h * 7 + (x.FirstName != null ? x.FirstName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            h = h * 7 + (x.LastName != null ? x.LastName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            ... other properties similarly ...
            return h;
        }
    }
}
```

If you really think that using the `string` key will work in all your cases, you can do it without the custom equality comparer:

```
// returns a Dictionary<string, List<string>>
var groupByEmployee = rowsDictionary
    .SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value)
    .GroupBy(s => s.LastName.ToUpper() + s.FirstName.ToUpper())
    .ToDictionary(
         s => s.Key,
         s => s.Select(x => x.Delivery_System).Distinct().ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks .. "for start" ? :) so Is there a more efficient way too? I really need to be careful with running out of memory stuff in this code, those dictioaries are like 110,000 items in it

Comment: for question 2: Yes, in actual code it also has an ID field, so it is combination of three things, I just posted two of them here for brevity.

Comment: for Question 3: Oh wow I did not know that, what things in my code do you suggest to replace with HashSet?

Comment: so just anyhwere I have a List<T> I can replace it with HashSet<T> ?

Comment: @user1899082: `HashSet` is a set, an unordered collection of **unique (distinct) items** (according to certain criteria), suitable for algorithms where you need to check if an item belongs to a set many times. If you need an ordered collection of items, including duplicates, or you don't need to constantly check if a collection contains an item, you should use a list. One thing is not clear: you can have multiple EmployeeSummaries, with equal `combinedKey`s but different `delivery_system` values?

Comment: Thanks for info. No my empSummaries have unique combinedKeys , in actual code they have an "ID" as part of the combinedKeys, I just omitted it here for brevity of code. But yes one employee can be in delivery system 50, 52, 12  and another employee in delivery system of 50,25

Comment: so here the  List<string> systems = null; you defined can be a HashSet?

Comment: @user1899082: I have updated my example with a LINQ expression which should create the result in a single line (well, split over several lines actually :). That is, if I didn't misunderstand your requirements.

Comment: @user1899082: that last snipped is actually your original code, with the string key.